# How to consume XEvent when using Xinput 2?

Tags: linux, x11, xinput, keyboard-input

I am looking at [this example](https://github.com/anko/xkbcat/blob/master/xkbcat.c). I'm trying to write a program that will run in background and listen to all keyboard events. That program should be able to discard some of the keyboard input. In before mentioned example, key logger doesn't consume events. I want to do something similar to [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows, but I don't seem to find my way around. Is it possible to do something like that using X11?